# ArgumentException "parameter is incorrect"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a code that converts memorystream to a png image, but I'm getting a *ArgumentException "parameter is incorrect"* error on *using(Image img = Image.FromStream(ms))*. It doesn't specify it any further so I don't know why I'm getting the error and what am I supposed to do to it.

Also, how do I use the Width parameter with *img.Save(filename + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);*? I know I can add parameters and it recognizes "Width", but I have no idea how it should be formatted so visual studio would accept it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        public string filename;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFile();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConvertFile();
        }

        private void OpenFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog d = new OpenFileDialog();

            if(d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filename = d.FileName;
                var fs = d.OpenFile();
                fs.CopyTo(ms);
            }
        }

        private void ConvertFile()
        {
            using(Image img = Image.FromStream(ms))
            {
                img.Save(filename + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I suspect the problem is with how you're reading the file here:

```
fs.CopyTo(ms);
```

You're copying the content of the file into the `MemoryStream`, but then leaving the `MemoryStream` positioned at the *end* of the data rather than the start. You can fix that by adding:

```
// "Rewind" the memory stream after copying data into it, so it's ready to read.
ms.Position = 0;
```

You should consider what happens if you click on the buttons multiple times though... and I'd strongly advise you to use a `using` directive for your `FileStream`, as currently you're leaving it open.

Comment: Good thing to know, but this didn't fix the issue

Comment: @SusiKette: Have you tried removing the UI side of things entirely? What if you just use `File.OpenRead` to open a stream to the file, then call `Image.FromStream` there? Does *that* work? What format is the file in to start with?

Comment: It's a raw file. Does that matter? It should still be able to read the bytes from the file. I know the file itself is image data because I've done a little bit of conversion by hand/manually, but the file is pretty big so a converter would definitely help. For now I just want the program to output a png file from the input data and then add things to get closer to my goal when I have a visual output to aid me with the conversion.

Comment: @SusiKette: Yes, it absolutely matters. You're asking the `Image` class to interpret the bytes *as an image* - so that needs to be in a format that it knows about. If by "raw file" you mean that there's no header information etc to explain the format, that's going to be a problem.

Comment: Is there still a way to define the necessary information?

Comment: @SusiKette: There are no overloads accepting an `ImageFormat` or anything like that, I'm afraid. (At least, I can't see anything similar.) I suspect the next research for you to do is searching for loading an image specifically from a raw file in .NET. It *may* be that you need to use a third party library for that, although I'd be surprised if there were really no way of doing it in the framework.